The conservative force
I read about the definition of the curl.
It's the measure of the rotation of the vector field around a specific point
I understand this, but I would like to know what does the "curl of the conservative is zero" physically mean? How can I visualise it?

Hi, welcome to Physics SE. A conservative force is defined by its doing no work on something that goes round a loop, so this is ultimately a calculus issue, whatever you personally regard as physical, imaginable or intuitive. Are we allowed to use contour integrals, Stokes's theorem etc. to answer your question?

"how can I imagin it" You need to be clearer on what you're asking for. The mathematics is there and tells us that it can be expressed as the gradient of a potential function barring other subtleties.

why was this question closed? it specifically asked about the physical interpretation of aa mathematical concept widely used in physics, which should be on-topic as far as I am concerned.

Remark

the curl it's the measure of the rotation of the vector field around a specific point

Before answering your question, I'd replace (local) "rotation" with (local, or elementary) "circuitation", since nothing really rotates when a vector field $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})$ is given.
Short answer
Qualitatively, the curl can be interpreted as a circuitation density, see below for derivation and details: thus, curl zero implies zero circuitation on every elementary closed path.
Since every close path can be built as the "sum" of elementary closed paths and integrals are additive, it's possible to go back from the local to the global definition of conservative fields.
Details
I'm trying to give you a description of the local behavior considering elementary closed path, and using series approximation of regular fields. Assuming $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})$ is a conservative field in a region $\Omega$, the line integral
$$\oint_{\ell} \mathbf{f} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{t}} = 0 \ ,$$
for all the closed lines $\ell \in \Omega$. By taking an elementary closed loop build with two vectors $d\mathbf{v}_1$, $d\mathbf{v}_2$,

the evaluation of the circuitation with mid-point values for integration reads
$$\begin{aligned}
d \Gamma & = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r} + \frac{d\mathbf{v}_1}{2}) \cdot d \mathbf{v}_1 + \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r} + d\mathbf{v}_1 + \frac{d\mathbf{v}_2}{2}) \cdot d\mathbf{v}_2 - \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r}+\frac{d\mathbf{v}_1}{2}+d\mathbf{v}_2) \cdot d\mathbf{v}_1 - \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r}+\frac{d\mathbf{v}_2}{2}) \cdot d\mathbf{v}_2 = \\
& = - d \mathbf{v}_2 \cdot \nabla \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r}) \cdot d\mathbf{v}_1 +  d \mathbf{v}_1 \cdot \nabla \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r}) \cdot d\mathbf{v}_2  + o(|d\mathbf{v}_i|)
\end{aligned}$$
and using Cartesian coordinates
$$\begin{aligned}
d \Gamma & = - dv^2_i \partial_i f_k(\mathbf{r}) dv^1_k + dv^1_i \partial_i f_k(\mathbf{r}) dv^2_k = \\
& = dv_i^1 \, dv_k^2 ( \partial_i f_k(\mathbf{r}) - \partial_k f_i(\mathbf{r}) ) = \dots \\
& = dv_i^1 \, dv_k^2 ( \delta_{il} \delta_{km} - \delta_{im}\delta_{kl} ) \partial_{l} f_m = \\ 
& = dv_i^1 \, dv_k^2 \varepsilon_{\alpha i k} \varepsilon_{\alpha l m} \partial_l f_m = \\
& = d \mathbf{v}_1 \times d \mathbf{v}_2 \cdot \nabla \times \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r}) = \\
& = dA \, \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \nabla \times \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r}) \ ,
\end{aligned}$$
with $\nabla \times \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})$ the curl of $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})$ in point $\mathbf{r}$ taken as the "origin" (and end) of the elementary path, and $d \mathbf{v}_1 \times d \mathbf{v}_2$ the elementary area of this path, with unit normal vector.
The last formula gives you a local "elementary" expression of the curl theorem: the circuitation over $\ell = \partial S$ equals the flux of the rotor through $S$.
Now, since for a potential field the elementary circuitation $d \Gamma$ of field $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})$ is zero for every possible path, then the curl of $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})$ must be zero as well.

An example might be the best way to see it.
Set up some electrodes that create a horizontal electric field. Make it so the field strength is proportional to height.
This is a non-conservative field. Start up high and throw an electron against the field. The field will decelerate it to a stop. At this point, move it straight down and release it. The weaker field will accelerate it. When it is below the starting point, move it back up to the starting point. It is going slower than when released.
Moving it up and down is a cheat, but we will gloss over that. The top and bottom legs illustrate the point. I could contrive a more complicated example that does not cheat and get the same answer.
This field has a non-zero curl at every point. You can see this by shrinking the loop to infinitesimal size around each point.

While @basics has the math right, I understand your question is about the physical interptetation. To answer this, we must understand what a force field is, since the definition of the rotation operator only really makes sense when applied to a field.
A force field is a way to mathematically describe how the force a body experiences due to an interaction varies with its position. Prime examples of this would be the electromagnetic field around an charge, or the flow of a fluid. In the first case, electrically charged bodies feel the Coulomb force. In the second case, they simply feel the fluid mechanically pushing them.
The rotation operator measures the change in a vector field as one goes around a closed path. As a force field has units of force, and a path has units of length, we can naively say that a path through a force field has units of force times length - precisely what is known as work. If now the rotation of a force field vanishes, meaning that there is no total change around a closed loop, we call the force field conservative. Going around a closed loop will result in no net work done.
The electric field of a point charge is a conservative field: Any work that must be done to push against the coulomb force will be compensated by the coulomb force pushing the object when going the other way to close the path. Mathematically, one can then show that such a conservative force field can always be written as the gradient of a potential. If we now instead consider again our other example of the fluid, we see that in general, going along a closed loop might require some work being done to work against the current along the entire path: this is especially the case when there are eddy currents involved. A trivial example would be pushing an object clockwise against a fluid rotating counterclockwise: obviously, this would require work along the entire path. One can even physically see the rotation involved.
